# When :system_mode = 'query' then null

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am creating trigger to get max invoice# in oracle forms 11g its working well.

But I need when `:system.mode in ('execute','query')` then trigger will not work.

I am trying

```
if :system.mode ='execute' then
   null;
else
   SELECT NVL(MAX(INV),0)+1 INTO :SA.INV FROM ALFA.SA WHERE MM_YY = :MM_YY;
end if;
```

But trigger give max invoice# in both modes. I need only in normal or inserting mode.

I also try

```
if :system.mode ='query' then
   null;
```

but not working. Trigger give max value to invoice#.

Comment: I am not sure but have you tried `ENTER-QUERY` or `QUERY` in caps mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SYSTEM.MODE` has 3 valid values:

- NORMAL
- ENTER-QUERY
- QUERY

all in uppercase. There's no `EXECUTE`.

---

Moreover, what you are doing is **wrong**. As long as it works in a single-user environment, it'll fail in a multi-user one because sooner or later two (or more) users will fetch the same `MAX(INV)` from the table which will make the `:SA.INV` **duplicate**. If it is a primary or unique key, you won't even be able to store it into the table (except for the first user who commits).

There is a way to do that (using a table which contains the next valid value, fetched by an autonomous transaction function), but - I'd suggest you to switch to a **sequence** or - if your database version supports it - **identity** column.

Comment: I tried (IF :SYSTEM.MODE = 'QUERY' THEN
    NULL;
    ELSE
SELECT NVL(MAX(INV),0)+1 INTO :SA.INV FROM ALFA.SA WHERE MM_YY = :MM_YY;
    END IF) ' But not working Also tried (IF :SYSTEM.MODE = 'NORMAL' THEN
    SELECT NVL(MAX(INV),0)+1 INTO :SA.INV FROM ALFA.SA WHERE MM_YY = :MM_YY;
        ELSE
        NULL;
        END IF;)

Comment: Display value of that system variable so that you'd see what you have. Use MESSAGE built-in to do it, e.g. `message('Current mode is ' || :system.mode);`